# Are geometric lines and $\mathbb{R}$ formally identical objects?

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-geometry

To be specific, are geometric lines as defined (for example) by Hilbert's axioms isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$? On the one hand, we clearly assume this to be the case every time we speak of the number "line." But on the other hand, $\mathbb{R}$ has special elements like "0" and "1" with important properties, whereas all points on a line are equivalent.

Also, constructing the reals is quite complicated: we need to first construct integers, then define rationals, then add in Dedekind cuts or Cauchy sequences or other fancy machinery to produce the continuum. Can lines be constructed from points in a similar way, or are we forced to assert their continuum properties through axioms? What I'm really looking for is a rigorous justification for treating the real number "line" as a line.

Comment: It really depends on how you define things---what do you mean by "isomorphic"?  what structures do you hope to preserve?  As sets, $\mathbb{R}$ and any line are isomorphic (in the sense that they have the same cardinality).  As topological spaces, they are isomorphic (in the sense that they are homeomorphic).  However, an arbitrary line and $\mathbb{R}$ are not generally isomorphic as, for example, vector spaces.

Comment: To clarify @XanderHenderson's final sentence, you have to choose a vector space structure on an arbitrary line before you can even ask if they are isomorphic as vector spaces. (but if you *do* choose one, it's going to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, unless you do something weird)